# How should I do clear screen on ocaml toplevel?

Tags: ocaml, ledit

I am using ocaml toplevel with ledit (ledit -l 100 ocaml) on Ubuntu 14.04. Since there is no way to do clear screen, all the time, I keep dwelling at the bottom of the screen.

I would like to know if there is a way to do clear screen at toplevel?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Have you already tried [utop](https://github.com/diml/utop)?

Comment: @Shamaoke No I have not, I like the minimalist approach of the original toplevel and libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try:

```
# Sys.command "clear";;
```

However, it is normal to dwell at the bottom of the screen. The command line has worked this way for at least 30 years :-)

Answer (score 8):

Sys.command "clear" is quite *functional* - it clears and returns an int :-)

My favourite is  `Ctrl+l` - unixoides only.

Answer (score 1):

You can try: `let clear = function x -> Sys.command("clear")+x;;`

Then everytime you call: `clear x;;` 
where x is an int your screen should be clean again.

Comment: let c = function () -> Sys.command("clear");;